# Use google.appengine.api.logservice outside of an app engine project?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to write a better way to view logs that color codes and allows filtering and such while developing locally on app engine, but I first need to figure out how to load the logs from an external python application.

This is the error I'm getting, and it's a bit over my head.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pretty_logs.py", line 20, in <module>
    for request in logservice.fetch(include_app_logs=True, start_time = time.tim
e() + since):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\logs
ervice\logservice.py", line 435, in __iter__
    self._advance()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\logs
ervice\logservice.py", line 449, in _advance
    response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apip
roxy_stub_map.py", line 94, in MakeSyncCall
    return stubmap.MakeSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apip
roxy_stub_map.py", line 321, in MakeSyncCall
    assert stub, 'No api proxy found for service "%s"' % service
AssertionError: No api proxy found for service "logservice"
```

Comment: You could install this tool, which does what you're trying to do:  https://github.com/dmnd/technicolor-yawn